# Get the size of compiled glsl shader uniform parameter from C++ code

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to get the size of uniform parameter in already compiled glsl shader program. I have found some functions to do it for default-typed uniforms only. But is there a way to do it for uniform parameters with custom type?

For example:

```
struct Sphere
{
    vec3 position;
    float raduis;
};

#define SPHERES 10
uniform Sphere spheres[SPHERES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your end goal basically is `spheres.length` and the result being `10`.

The most optimal way would be to have that length stored elsewhere, as it isn't possible to change the size after the shader has been compiled anyways.

---

There's no simple way to get the length of the array. Because there isn't any array per se. When compiled each element of the array (as well as each element of the struct) ends up becoming their own individual uniform. Which is evident by the need of doing:

```
glGetUniformLocation(program, "spheres[4].position")
```

The thing is that if your shader only uses `spheres[4].position` and `spheres[8].position` then all the other `spheres[x].position` are likely to be optimized away and thus won't exist.

---

*So how do you get the uniform array length?*

You could accomplish this by utilizing `glGetActiveUniform()` and regex or `sscanf()`. Say you want to check how many `spheres[x].position` is available, then you could do:

```
GLint count;
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, &count);

const GLsizei NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 64

GLint location, size;
GLenum type;
GLchar name[NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
GLsizei nameLength;

int index, charsRead;

for (GLint i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    glGetActiveUniform(program, (GLuint)i, NAME_MAX_LENGTH, &nameLength, &size, &type, name);

    if (sscanf(name, "spheres[%d].position%n", &index, &charsRead) && (charsRead == nameLength))
    {
        // Now we know spheres[index].position is available
    }
}
```

*You can additionally compare `type` to `GL_FLOAT` or `GL_FLOAT_VEC3` to figure out which data type it is.*

Remember that if you add an `int count` and increment it for each match. Then even if `count` is `3` at the end. That doesn't mean it's element `0, 1, 2` that's available. It could easily be element `0, 5, 8`.

Additional notes:

- `name` is a null terminated string
- `%n` is the number of characters read so far

Comment: Thanks for this big explanation, but my question is how get the size of uniform variable by it's name if it has user-defined type. Sorry, I have added array there to show the hardest case, but it made my question unclear, I guess. So, here is simpler uniform declaration: `uniform Sphere spheres;` and I want to get the size of "spheres" variable from my C++ code.

Comment: My answer already covered that? Use `type`. The thing is that there is no `sizeof(sphere[i])` because there is no `sphere[i]` per se. Only individual elements which each map to a uniform. So you have to check for every `sphere[i].*`. Then check for their type and then you can conclude the final size. Thus if you want to check the final size of the array, you had to check for every `sphere.*`.